# R markdown knitting error (infinite recursion)

Tags: r, r-markdown, infinite-recursion

I am trying to knit an R markdown document into pdf, but it keeps failing and shows this message only:
**Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Execution halted**

It has nothing to do with my codes, because R is failing to knit even an empty R markdown file. I believe something is wrong with my settings. Should I delete and re-install R?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I recommend going to project options (under tools) and disable "Restore .RData into workspace at startup" and restart R

Comment: @WietsedeVries My problem persists. But thank you for your attention.